# Не работает обработчик php для бота Telegram

Tags: php, telegram-bot

Не работает обработчик php для бота Telegram
Установил вебхук с помощью url

```
$urlwh= "https://api.telegram.org/bot{$token}/setWebhook?url=".urlencode('https://site/dir/bot.php');
```

Телеграм ответил ok - true  и что хук установлен, а у файл bot.php добавил такие команды что-бы отследить что приселает телеграм

```
$tes = serialize(array_merge($_POST,$_GET));
file_put_contents(date("H_i_s").'.tmm', $tes);
```

При отправки боту команди файл на bot.php сервере  не запускается потому-что файлы tmm не создаются почему? на сайте есть самозавершащийся сертификат летскрипт

Answer (score 1):

Попробуй принимать данные вот этой строчкой 
`file_get_contents("php://input")`